# Library like SoundManager 2 without flash for mobile phones?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile, soundmanager2

I'm working on a HTML5 game for mobile phone. The sound work sometimes and disappear others.
DO you have any idea about library like SoundManager 2 without flash for mobile phones ?

Answer (score 2):

To use HTML5 with SoundManager simply add the settings:

```
useHTML5Audio: true,
preferFlash: true,
```

This will always use HTML5 over flash, and will work on iOS products.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-ioshtml5/index.html

This should help with HTML5 in ios products. Android can have flash, so normal SoundManager should work there.

As long as your sounds are mp3, wav or acc safari should play them fine, so it would help if you use the debug version of soundmanager2 and post the error you get when the sound doesn't work, because it might well be a separate problem that can be solved without a different audio library.

Comment: preferFlash: false,  ?

Answer (score 0):

You could look into [HTML5 Audio API](http://www.w3.org/TR/webaudio/#APIOverview). I have to say though, at this point support is little so be sure to check out if Safari on iOS is supported.

Answer (score 0):

There's http://zohararad.github.io/audio5js/ which is a simpler SoundManager alternative.